# How to launch watch mode in Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core 1.1.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run my web application in watch mode referring to [How to watch for file changes "dotnet watch" with Visual Studio ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152854/how-to-watch-for-file-changes-dotnet-watch-with-visual-studio-asp-net-core/40188330) but in newer version (core 1.1.1) I can't find launchSettings.json file, so where put settings? I installed Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools but I don't have a button "watch" in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the launchSettings.json in the Solution Explorer under the menu Properties. There you can add the settings for your "watch" profile.

You can add following profile settings:

```
"Watch": {
    "executablePath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\dotnet.exe",
    "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
    "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
}
```

[launchSettings.json in Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w1GD.png)

Comment: Did so. Getting the following in the console:
`Using launch settings from <pathto file>
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2.ContainsKey(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Run.LaunchSettings.LaunchSettingsManager.Try....
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
watch : Exited with error code 1`