# It's not work to set launch.json commandLineArgs watch run in visual studio 2019 4.8.03752

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

It's not work to set launch.json commandLineArgs watch run  in visual studio 4.8.03752.

my launch.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "WebApplication23": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my visual studio version :

[image: image-20200730170402853]

I edited some code when program running but system show `Warning    ENC1003 Changes made in project 'WebApplication23' will not be applied while the application is running`,system didn't rebuild code.

[image: image-20200730170631827]

I've tried below page's method but it also not work

- [How to launch watch mode in Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core 1.1.1 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703858/how-to-launch-watch-mode-in-visual-studio-2017-asp-net-core-1-1-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according : [dnx - How to watch for file changes "dotnet watch" with Visual Studio ASP.NET Core - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40152854/how-to-watch-for-file-changes-dotnet-watch-with-visual-studio-asp-net-core)

`ASP.NET 2.x or 3.x` need to change to below json.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "Watch": {
      "executablePath": "dotnet.exe",
      "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
      "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:5000/",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and system will rebuild code :
[image: image-20200730181559434]