# Recompiling an ASP.NET Core Application in Rider without repeatedly rerunning it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, projects-and-solutions, rider, recompile

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application in Rider in which I'm frequently editing the code and as a result having to repeatedly manually stop and start the application, which is highly inconvenient.

To solve this, I tried various approaches:

1. Rebuilding the application while running doesn't work. First, I get a warning:
   [image: warning]
   If I click build, the solution is rebuilt, but any code changes aren't reflected in the running web server. E.g if I changed the string `"welcome"` to `"goodbye"`, rebuilding still shows `welcome` after rebuilding.
2. `dotnet watch run`. Adding this command as an external tool to run in the pre-launch configuration does get save-based recompilation working. However, this doesn't integrate with the built-in runner. Since `dotnet watch run` starts its own web server, Rider's run command never actually runs. As a result, Rider doesn't detect that the application has started running, but instead thinks that `dotnet watch run` is some pre-launch task to begin *before* running. With debugging, I am unable to hit any breakpoints for this reason as well.

Is there any other way I can quickly rebuild an ASP.NET Core project while running it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you're after is Razor file compilation. This will rebuild your views upon editing them without restarting the server.

If you add this package reference:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.0" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
```

and add this snippet to your startup:

```cs
public IWebHostEnvironment Env { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    IMvcBuilder builder = services.AddRazorPages();

#if DEBUG
    if (Env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
    }
#endif

    // code omitted for brevity
}
```

you should now have the views being rebuilt. You can read more about this in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

**EDIT:**

If you would also like to have all files updated (not just views), there are a couple of options:

1. You can add a Live Reload middleware [using this package](http://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.AspnetCore.LiveReload).
2. You can use `dotnet-watch` and to rebuild and run the project when it is saved. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53225064/6939988) on how to do that.

Comment: I was aware of this, but doesn’t it only apply to view files? Ideally, I was looking for something that would allow me to do this with regular files as well.

Comment: Correct, this is only for views. For regular files i.e. live reload, there is this community option https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.AspnetCore.LiveReload. The built in option is being tracked at https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5456.

Comment: In addition to the live reload, I found a way to integrate the `dotnet watch` script better with Rider by [adding it as a launch profile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53225064/6525260). I think you should add it to your answer for completeness. Thanks!