# Error after modifying launchSettings: The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I'm setting up my project to use dotnet watch run in my launchSettings.json under Visual Studio 2019 Preview 16.9.0

Below is my `launchSettings.json`

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyWebsite": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "dotnet",
      "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
      "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the ouput when I hit `CTRL+F5`

```
watch : Started
The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.
A usable launch profile could not be located.
[17:38:49 INF] Starting up
[17:38:49 INF] User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
[17:38:50 INF] Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
[17:38:50 INF] Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
[17:38:50 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[17:38:50 INF] Hosting environment: Development
[17:38:50 INF] Content root path: C:\dev\MyWebsite\src\MyWebsite
```

I don't understand why I have this message :

```
The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.
A usable launch profile could not be located.
```

According to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666418/1026105 this is not supposed to happen.

How can I troubleshoot this messages ?

Comment: Ok, just changing the profile name fixed this... No clue why it happened.

Answer (score 6):

just Change

**"MyWebsite": {
"commandName": "Executable",**

to

**"MyWebsite": {
"commandName": "Project",**

Comment: Could you please add some informations, how that answers the question?

Answer (score 3):

For me, changing `commandName` from `Executable` to `Project` made the error message go away, but also disabled the `dotnet watch` behaviour altogether.

I fixed the issue by adding a separate `Project` profile *as well as* the `Executable` one - I assume the `Project` profile then serves as the 'default' profile to which the error message refers.

So it's:

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyWebsite": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "MyWebsite-Watch": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "dotnet",
      "commandLineArgs": "watch run",
      "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```