# How to run maui apps with dotnet cli

Tags: maui, .net-maui

With typical web apps we do the following.

```
dotnet new webapp --name ./MyNewWebApp --framework net6.0

cd MyNewWebApp

dotnet build ./MyNewWebApp.csproj

dotnet run --project ./MyNewWebApp.csproj
```

And it works. Now I trying to play around with [dotnet MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui) projects.

With MAUI the project file is complex when compared to a web project.

It has multiple target frameworks, and the csproj file looks as follows.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        ...
</PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        ...
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Further more, the launchSettings.json file is quite simple.

```json
  "profiles": {
    "Windows Machine": {
      "commandName": "MsixPackage",
      "nativeDebugging": false
    }
  }
```

With visual studio I am able to create and run them. The Visual Studio launch tool bar shows the following.

[image: Visual Studio Tool bar for running the MAUI app]

So now with MAUI project, ***build*** command works fine.

```
dotnet build ./MauiCliBasic.csproj
```

But when I execute the ***run*** command, I get the following errors.

```
dotnet run --project ./MauiCliBasic.csproj
```

> The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.
> A usable launch profile could not be located.
> Unable to run your project
> Your project targets multiple frameworks. Specify which framework to run using '--framework'.

And when I specify the framework I still get the errors.

```
dotnet run --project ./MauiCliBasic.csproj --framework net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0
```

> The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.
> A usable launch profile could not be located.

So what am I missing?

[image: running dotnet MAUI project from command line]

Answer (score 1):

This is a `known issue` that being tracked in these two threads: [Unable to run Windows application from command line](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5975) , [Unable to run Windows application from .NET SDK command line](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2922), feel free to follow up with them. BTW, it might be related to the settings in the `launchSettings.json` file. You can refer to [Error after modifying launchSettings: The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688268/error-after-modifying-launchsettings-the-launch-profile-default-could-not-b).