# How to configure MAUI to launch a debug session for a specific platform

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I am using the Visual Studio plugin SwitchStartupProject
https://heptapod.host/thirteen/switchstartupproject/

Here I can quickly switch between multiple "sets" of projects to debug. For instance:

- webapi + WPF backend management application
- webapi + App (Xamarin.Forms.App.Windows)
  and
- webapi + App (Xamarin.Forms.App.Android)

Now that I'm moving to Maui, and the Windows and Android platforms are "in the same project" I don't know how to configure it to launch a specific platform.

This is the configuration file that needs 'specifics' to launch a certain Maui platform.

```
{
  "Version": 3,
  "ListAllProjects": false,
  "MultiProjectConfigurations": {
    "Maui + WebApi (Debug)": {
      "Projects": {            
        "BB.Maui": {},
        "BB.WebApi2": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue -- did you figure anything out?  I can get it to launch the correct platform by setting the MAUI project as the startup project, selecting the platform from the debug button, then switching back to the multi-project startup, but this seems to cause build issues for me when working with platform-specific code.

Comment: I don't think this can not yet be fixed with a command line parameter or a launch profile setting. It seems to be related to a number of open issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74271977/how-to-run-maui-apps-with-dotnet-cli